# Hand saws to cut OSB type panels

Tags: cutting, demolition, saw, osb

I want to cut OSB panel on an old shed into pieces and they will go into garbage.
I've searched for some advice regarding it and found out that a handsaw can be used for small amount of work.
Please advice which hand saws can be used. I tried doing it 15$ `STANLEY 15-INCH TRADECUT PANEL SAW` but it's too difficult.
The priority is the speed, not the quality of cutting.

Comment: I am leaving this as a comment since it does not answer your specific question. Since OSB is pretty weak across its face, I would lay the sheet out on another item that will hold up one side and step in the middle to start breaking it in halves. Keep doing so, until it fits in what you want it to.

Comment: Sledgehammer is indeed the third option here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are categorically opposed to electric tools, I'd seriously consider a reciprocating saw. They are ideal for this type of rough work and will get through it a *lot* faster than a hand saw. The traditional brand name is "Sawzall", but all the major tool manufacturers have similar products. If you have a preferred brand of battery powered tool, then I'd go for the battery-powered version that matches your existing batteries/chargers. For Ryobi (Home Depot), [that is this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-ONE-18V-Cordless-Reciprocating-Saw-Tool-Only-P519/312462409):

[image: Ryobi saw]

A corded version will, typically, give you more power. What is best for you will depend on how much you will use it, availability of utility power and other factors.

Comment: Looks like this option is the best. Especially when this kind of saw costs not so much.

Comment: i got one for $18 at harbor fright.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fixated on a hand saw, use a pruning saw (for cutting tree limbs) as they have a lot of set (teeth spread wide to allow a lot of clearance) and relatively coarse (fast-cutting) teeth.

Comment: It's really hard to select among your answers. I'll select the one I'll actually use. If I could, I'd select both. Thank you very much. At least, I can upvote.

Comment: If another answer suits your actual use case better, then it's the one to get the checkmark, and no issues at all with that. That's how things are supposed to work.